# How do I multiply a class by a number that is not defined in the class?

Tags: python

```
import math
class Gaussian:
  def __init__(self, a=1, b=2):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
  
  def __str__(self):
    return("%s*exp(-(x**2/%s))"%(self.a,self.b**2))
  
  def derive(self):
    a = (self.a*-2)/(self.b**2)
    b = self.b
    return(str(Gaussian(a,b)) + "*x")
  
  def __mul__(self,multi):
    a = self.a*multi.a
    b = self.b**2
    b = math.sqrt((1/((multi.b**2)/(b*multi.b**2)+(b)/((multi.b**2)*b))))
    return(str(Gaussian(a,b)))
    

  def __truediv__(self,divide):
    if self.a == divide.a*-1:
      return(-1.0)
    else:
      diva = self.a/divide.a
      divb = self.b**2
      divb2 = divide.b**2
      divb += math.sqrt(1/((divb2)/(divb*divb2)-(divb/(divb2*divb))))
  
      return(str(Gaussian(diva,divb)))
```

Here I use the class Gaussian to represent a Gaussian function. I can do multiplication between 2 classes of Gaussian but not if the second input is not a class. The code I am trying to run is:

```
g1=Gaussian(3,-1)
g2=g1*3
print(g2)
g3=g2*2.5
print(g3)
```

This should multiply the `self.a` value by 3.

Each time I try to run it I get the error `'int' object has no attribute a`. I have no idea what to try to fix this.

Comment: Add code to `__mul__` to handle that case?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `__mul__` function, you can check the type of `multi` before doing any work with it.

```
from numbers import Number

def __mul__(self, multi):
  if isinstance(multi, Gaussian):
    # Multiply two Gaussians
    ...
  elif isinstance(multi, Number):
    # Multiply Gaussian by number
    ...
  else:
    # Don't know how to handle it, so return NotImplemented
    return NotImplemented
```

Returning `NotImplemented` if the type isn't what we expect allows Python's `__rmul__` dispatch to work correctly. And speaking of `__rmul__`, you'll probably want to implement that as well. `__rmul__` will be called if someone writes `3 * Gaussian(...)` with the `Gaussian` on the *right*. Since multiplication is probably commutative in your case, you can just delegate to (regular) multiplication in the opposite order.

```
def __rmul__(self, multi):
    return self * multi
```